# Java preincrement and postincrement operators

Tags: java, increment

```
public class Sample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        //part 1
        int i=1;
        i=i++;
        i=++i;
        i=i++;
        System.out.println(i);

        //part 2
        i=1;
        int a=i++;
        a=++i;
        a=i++;
        System.out.println(a+"\n"+i);
    }
}
```

**Output**

**2

3

4**

Yesterday my friend asked this question. I little bit confused about this. **part 1** prints the **i** value as **2**. Post increment is not working here. But in the **part 2**, it works. I can understand the **part 2** but i have confused in **part 1**. How actually it works? Can anybody make me understand?

Comment: Are you asking about Java, C, or C++?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I'm not totally sure it matters.

Comment: The question is in `JAVA` . Is it ?

Comment: not only in java @Deepak

Comment: I should know why there is down vote for my question?

Comment: @Kumar Most likely because your question involved post and pre increment/decrement which is an extremely heavily covered topic (although I did down vote it).

Comment: It means that we should not ask the question which covered such topics even we have doubt in that? @jared

Comment: @Kumar Well, I'm surprised this hasn't been flagged as a duplicate.  Usually if someone thinks that, they will give a question which represents essentially the same question.  But in answer to your question, yes, you should try to avoid asking questions which can be answered by a relatively simple search.  It's unlikely that you will find an exact match to your question but that doesn't mean that you cannot figure out your answer from previous questions/answers.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart, no, all three languages are mandated to give the same output for this snippet, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Because i was not copied the question from anywhere @jared

Comment: @Kumar Yes, you have not copied this question. Jared is trying to tell you that explanation for Pre & Post incrementors are covered in detail in Stackoverflow itself. He and the other downvoters want you search for the available answers before posting a question. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: sorry about that, I actually meant that I did _not_ down vote it (note that the modifier "although" in my parenthesis doesn't match what I stated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part one should print `i = 2`.  This is because:

```
public class Sample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        //part 1
        int i=1;
        // i++ means i is returned (which is i = 1), then incremented, 
        //  therefore i = 1 because i is incremented to 2, but then reset 
        //  to 1 (i's initial value)
        i=i++;
        // i is incremented, then returned, therefore i = 2
        i=++i;
        // again, first i is returned, then incremented, therefore i = 2 
        //  (see first statement)
        i=i++;
        System.out.println(i);

        //part 2
        i=1;
        // first i is returned then incremented, so i = 2, a = 1
        int a=i++;
        // i is incremented then returned, so i = 3 and a = 3
        a=++i;
        // i is first returned, then incremented, so a = 3 and i = 4
        a=i++;
        System.out.println(a+"\n"+i);
    }
}
```

Perhaps the simplest way to understand this is to introduce some extra variables.  Here is what you have:

```
// i = i++
temp = i;
i = i + 1;
i = temp; // so i equals the initial value of i (not the incremented value)

// i = ++i;
i = i + 1;
temp = i;
i = temp; // which is i + 1

// i = i++
temp = i;
i = i + 1;
i = temp; // so i equals the previous value of i (not i + 1)
```

Notice the difference in order of when the `temp` variable is set--either *before* or *after* the increment depending on whether or not it's a post-increment (`i++`) or a pre-increment (`++i`).

Comment: I understood it from your example with extra variables. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `i = i++` does not work in the way you expect it to work, is because post increment (the way you used it in) works like this:

1. Get the value of `i`
2. Increment original (copied in step one) `i` by one.
3. Set new `i` value to the original value.

So then `i` would still be `i`

Answer (score 0):

In `Java`

```
   //part 1
    int i = 1;
    i = i++; // i is still 1 since increment will rest by the assignment.
    i = ++i; // i+1=2 (since prefix increment)
    i = i++; // i is still 2
    System.out.println(i); // out put 2

    //part 2
    i = 1;
    int a = i++; // a is 1
    a = ++i; //a=1+2(since i++ now i is 2)=3
    a = i++;// a still 3
    System.out.println(a + "\n" + i); // now a is 3 is 4(since i++)
```

Read [prefix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1) and [postfix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) operator in `Java`.

Comment: Can you explain more elaborately how its store in a memory and how it is processing?

Answer (score 0):

ok i think already you understood the second part and your confusion in first part

```
++i will increment the value of i, and then return the incremented value.

 i = 1;
 j = ++i;
 here -->i is 2, j is 2
i++ will increment the value of i, but return the original value that i held before being incremented.

 i = 1;
 j = i++;
 here -->i is 2, j is 1)
```

check the example above from that you can understand easly what happends here ....

as per your code

```
int i=1;
        i=i++;
        i=++i;
        i=i++;
        System.out.println(i);

first i=i++;
```

then the value of i will be 1

```
then next setp i=++i;
```

then it will be incremented by 1 and now i will be 2

```
next step again i=i++;
```

then also i value remain same that is 2 ! // if the last step is i=++i; then the result will be 3

Comment: why i++ in the first statement is not incremented in the next line?

Comment: after the statement definitely it will be incremented to 2 but in your the matter is in i=++i; statement i will return first so value of i will be again 2

Answer (score 0):

Find the byte code of `i=i++`

```
2: iload_1  ; load to stack (local = 1, stack = 1)
3: iinc          1, 1; increment local variable (local =2, stack = 1)
6: istore_1 ; store value from stack to local variable (local = 1 )
```

Here we are storing old value from stack to local variable. Also find the comments in below code to see all the value changes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    //part 1
    int i=1;
    i=i++;// i=1 here i will be assigned with 1. increment will not affect
    i=++i;// i=2 
    i=i++;// i=2
    System.out.println(i);

    //part 2
    i=1;
    int a=i++;// a=1, i=2
    a=++i;// a=3, i= 3
    a=i++;// a=3, i=4
    System.out.println(a+"\n"+i);
}
```